# d3, data .enter, different groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have my data separated in a dict of arrays. `var BTNDATA={'B0':[0],'B1':[1] }`

When I press a button, I only want that row of circles to update. (i have 5 buttons, 5 rows)

I can on click add a svg circle element.  I update the BTNDATA dict by pushing a 1 to that dicts array. `BTNDATA[B0].push(1)`

This seems to update all keys arrays, and not just that specific one.

The problem is I just want to display a corresponding circle everytime its button is pushed (ie rows).  I cannot separate the row elements for the cy attribute.

I dont understand why I cant just push to a dict of arrays?  I tried to create a slice of the array from the dict, no luck . I tried creating separate groups, addig appending to those groups and not just the svg container.

here is the d3 update enter exit code:

```
function addCrl( bi, crldt) {
var i, btni, crl, shm, drow;

//data
drow = BTNDATA[bi].slice()

crl = svg1.selectAll("circle") 
         .data(drow)
//update

//enter
crl.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr('class', function(){ return 'c'+btni})
    .attr('cx', function() {
        return btni + 13
    })
    .attr('cy', function(){
        return drow.length * 2;
    } )
    .attr("r",13)
    .style("fill","red")

//exit  
dlt(crl,bi)
crl.exit()
    .remove()


}
```

Here is the loop where I call it:

```
function addBtnClk(bid) {
d3.select('#'+bid).on("click", function() {
    BTNDATA[bid].push(1);
    var crldt = BTNDATA[bid].slice()
    addCrl( bid, crldt );
});
}

function main(){
var i;
//add buttons/eventhandler
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    domBtn( pr[i], ky[i] )
    addBtnClk( ky[i] )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no dicts in Javascript -- what you're talking about is an object. The syntax you're looking for is `BTNDATA.B0.push(1)` or `BTNDATA['B0'].push(1)`. With your current code, the variable `B0` is dereferenced to index into `BTNDATA`, which gives you undesirable results.

Comment: I am passing the key as string variable. (ie I created var ky = Object.keys(BTNDATA).  Then loop through that array, into a function(bid) { ... BTNDATA[bid].push(1) }.   Do you know if d3 allows this, or if it all gets mixed up in the way it selects dom elements?  Ive seen examples where you can swith an entire svg by clicking different buttons that switch the entire data; but not part of it... maybe it messes up d3 DOM indexing of data somehow...?  The way its right now, any selected BUTTON pushes to all the BTNDATA keys.  (--argh)

Comment: It would help if you could post a complete working example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/syntax22/TS8Zh/1/  (not sure if doesnt work because of jsfiddle mistake, or because of original mistake; thanks for the response though btw)

Comment: Working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/TS8Zh/3/ -- you've assigned references to the same element to all the members (`emp`), so there was only one array of values that was updated.